# Python Pandas Crosstabs

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

New to Pandas and fairly new to Python.  I’m trying to produce a crosstabs report from the following data – just showing a few rows.

```
PALLET_ID AISLE NUM_PALLETS
7197033 AH  1
7197035 AC  1
7197035 AC  1
7197035 AC  1
7197035 AC  1
7197035 AC  1
```

I Sofastats I get a simple crosstab table of frequency of pallets within aisles - I.e. pallets down the left and aisles along the top.  (New Stackoverflow account doesn't allow images).

I am trying to do this in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataF = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('S:\misc\multistorepick\mstorepick2.csv'))
dataF
Out[8]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 915 entries, 0 to 914
Data columns (total 3 columns):
PALLET_ID      915  non-null values
AISLE          915  non-null values
NUM_PALLETS    915  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
```

Then following the handedness by gender example in the Python for Data Analysis book

```
Xtab = pd.crosstab(dataF.PALLET_ID,dataF.AISLE,margins=True)

Xtab
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 78 entries, 7197033 to All
Data columns (total 13 columns):
AA     78  non-null values
AB     78  non-null values
AC     78  non-null values
AD     78  non-null values
AE     78  non-null values
AF     78  non-null values
AG     78  non-null values
AH     78  non-null values
AJ     78  non-null values
AK     78  non-null values
AL     78  non-null values
BG     78  non-null values
All    78  non-null values
dtypes: int64(13)
```

I’m doing something very dumb.  Can someone please tell me what it is?

Comment: What's the problem / question? Your last output is a more compact formatting for wide or long DataFrames. Try `Xtab.head()` and see if it looks correct.

Comment: Unfortunatley I can't post an image as this is a new stackoverflow account. but I'm after a crosstab report with pallets on the left, aisles along the top and the cells containing the frequency of pallets by aisle.  a bit like the age group Vs car in http://www.sofastatistics.com/wiki/doku.php?id=help:report_tables

Comment: I think the code is correct, you only get a *summary view* of your dataframe, what you see is not the dataframe itself. Try eg ``Xtab.head()``

Comment: Thankyou both  - the .head worked  - how can I show everything not just the head?

Comment: Just worked it out with Xtab.to_csv.