# why pd.crosstab does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

The data is from the book "Python for Data Analysis", chp 8, Bar Plots

```
tips = pd.read_csv('ch8/tips.csv')
party_counts = pd.crosstab(tips.day,tips.size)
```

when I run the above codes, I find I can not get the result as the book shows.

```
In [70]: party_counts
Out[70]:
size 1 2 3 4 5 6
day
Fri 1 16 1 1 0 0
Sat 2 53 18 13 1 0
Sun 0 39 15 18 3 1
Thur 1 48 4 5 1 3
```

my result is

```
In[36]: party_counts
Out[36]: 
col_0  1708
day        
Fri      19
Sat      87
Sun      76
Thur     62
```

I test tips' type

```
In[49]: tips.dtypes
Out[49]: 
total_bill    float64
tip           float64
sex            object
smoker         object
day            object
time           object
size            int64
dtype: object
```

while I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351001/python-pandas-crosstabs) which also has one column is int can get the crosstab result.

so, anything wrong with me?
ps, my pandas version is '0.20.2', python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*size* is an attribute of the dataframe to get the number of elements from it, if you have a size column, you need to use `['size']` to avoid confusion:

```
pd.crosstab(tips.day, tips['size'])
```